# What is induced EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I am confused what happens in a coil when flux linkage is changed. What I know about EMF is:

> Potential difference between terminals of a battery before it is connected to a circuit.

Is this valid for induced EMF also?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please refrain from asking too many questions in one question and further, I am not sure whether you could not maybe go and read up a bit about electromagnetism and then maybe come back with a more specific question ...

Answer (score 2):

It is noteworthy to mention an excerpt from Purcell:

> The *electromotive force* was earlier defined  as **the work per unit charge involved in moving a charge around a circuit** containing a voltaic cell. We now broaden the definition of emf to include **any influence that causes charge to *circulate* around a closed path**.

More specifically, Feynman writes:

> [...] More specifically, emf is the tangential component of the force per unit charge , integrated along the wire once around the circuit. This quantity is equal, therefore, to the total work done on a single charge that travels one around the circuit.

So, emf is basically the work done by any means that circulate the electron around a closed curve.

In electrostatics, the curl of the electric field was zero since they were conservative and hence there is no non-zero circulation; but in general, the fields are not conservative.

Using Lorentz Force, we get 
\begin{align}\mathscr E_\textrm{induced} \equiv \textrm{Electromotive Force} &=\int_\Gamma (\mathbf E + \mathbf v\times \mathbf B)\,\mathrm d\mathbf s \\&=- \int_{S(t_0)}\, \left(\dfrac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}\right)\bigg|_{t~=~t_0}\,\mathrm d\mathbf a +\int_{\Gamma}\,(\mathbf v\times \mathbf B)\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf s \\& = \left(-\int_{S(t_0)}\, \left(\dfrac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}\right)\bigg|_{t~=~t_0}\,\mathrm d\mathbf a\right)+\left(-\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\, \int_{\mathrm dS}\mathbf B(t_0)\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf a\right) \\ &=-\dfrac{\mathrm d\Phi_\textrm{total}}{\mathrm dt}\;.\end{align}

Comment: Then what is difference between emf and voltage?

Comment: Scalar Potential doesn't exist for a non-conservative field.

Comment: @Beginner It's a technical difference based on the source of the thing.   As far as their influence on a charge is concerned, they are the same.

Comment: Mafia, I downvoted this because it chucks out a couple of quotes followed by a lump of maths, and it doesn't actually _explain_ anything.

Comment: So, don't you think OP required the definition which Purcell was explaining his quote clearly followed by Feynman?

Comment: I would appreciate if I can make the post better and oblige you to revert the downvote @JohnDuffield; waiting for suggestions.

Comment: Some attempt at explanation will make me revert the downvote. The whole thing about stack exchange is _if you cannot explain it to your grandmother you do not understand it yourself_. IMHO answering a question ought to help you to get your own thoughts in order. It helps you to understand things, or understand that you don't. Note that neither Purcell nor Feynman knew how a magnet works.

Comment: Check @JohnDuffield; edited.

Comment: Hmmn. I'm still not happy with it, but you've made a bit of an effort and you have given an answer after all, so I've reversed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of emf in a coil is the amount of work needed to move a unit positive charge around the coil. That is $\epsilon$ = $\int_C E.\vec {ds}$, where C denotes the coil contour. For an electrostatic E, $\epsilon$ is obviously zero as the integral around a closed loop vanishes, but for a non conservative electric field, $\epsilon$ is non zero.